# how to disbale scrolling on whole page except the selected div in html web page

Tags: javascript, html, web, scroll

I am using scrolling in the html web page but problem is that it works on whole page but i want that to work on the div on which i am calling the scrolling function here is my code

```
<script>
var startPos;

function init(){
  var scrollArea = document.getElementById('holder');
  scrollArea.addEventListener('touchstart', function(event){
    touchstartHandler(event);
  }, false);

  scrollArea.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event){
    touchmoveHandler(event);
  }, false);

  scrollArea.addEventListener('touchend', function(event){
    touchendHandler(event);
  }, false);
}

function touchstartHandler(e){
  startPos = e.touches[0].pageY;
}

function touchmoveHandler(e){
  var touch = e.touches[0];
  var targetBox = e.currentTarget.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
  e.preventDefault();

  var fingerMoved = startPos - touch.pageY;
  startPos = touch.pageY;

  targetBox.scrollTop = targetBox.scrollTop + fingerMoved;
}
</script>
```

Comment: touch devices somehow do not update the scrollTop property. why don't you change the targetBox.style.top instead of scrollTop ?

Comment: why do you want javascript/jquery for scroll. So, "Holder" gets the scroll ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution, 
To cut off the scroll of your ENTIRE page.

Set CSS:

```
html, body{overflow:hidden;}
/* or */
html, body{overflow-y: hidden;}
```

This will get rid of your page scrolling completely. 
Then just set the elements on the page that you want to scroll to scroll.
Which in all honesty you don't even need javascript for, but javascript does provide better functionality.